# Cast iron pot in cabin luggage?

Tags: air-travel, legal, hand-luggage

I want to take a Le Creuset pot in my cabin luggage on united airlines from San Francisco to Australia. Any chance they may consider it a dangerous object? Anyone have any experience carrying this type of item?

Comment: What airline are you flying with? Do you have a picture of the pot?

Comment: Also note http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39782/is-there-a-weight-limit-for-carry-on-luggage-with-united-airlines there is no weight limit which in case of a Le Creuset pot (depending on size, can be 15lbs alone) is a very relevant question.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are departing from the US, what you can bring on board is governed by the US TSA regulations.  The TSA has a [handy web site](http://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items) where you can search for various objects to learn whether or not they are allowed (see the search feature in the upper right).  Searching for "pot" turns up a variety of hits including "metal pot", "cooking pot" and "pot for cooking".  All of them have the answer:

> You may transport this item in carry-on baggage or in checked baggage.